# Sometimes: <nine-patch> requires a valid src attribute

Tags: android, resources, png, styles

I sometimes get reports of this error shown above in my applications. I never see this error during development and test. The applications is for 2.1 and higher. I test in 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 (emulator) and real devices (except 2.3).

Here's the part of a layout file that produces this error (the view is part of a TableLayout):

```
 <TextView
 style="@style/ActivityTitleBar"
 android_layout_span="2"
 android:layout_weight="2"
 android:text="@string/txt_appname" />
```

Here's the style definition:

```
<style name="ActivityTitleBar">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/titlebar</item>
<item name="android:gravity">center</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
<item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
<item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

In res/drawable is a XML file with this content:

```
<nine-patch
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:dither="true"
android:src="@drawable/titlebar" />
```

The titlebar.png is located in my drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi and drawable-mdpi folders.

I don't have any clue what device or Android release causes this error.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

HJW

Here's the stack-trace-report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.x.y.android/de.x.y.android.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2132)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1654)
at de.x.y.android.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:46)
at de.X.Y.android.Main.onCreate(Main.java:190)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1065)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:332)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
... 25 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/titlebar.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020003
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:338)
... 29 more
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <nine-patch> requires a valid src attribute
at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.inflate(NinePatchDrawable.java:262)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
... 32 more
```

Comment: Finally what solution you made ?

Comment: [Related post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700777/android-api-21-9patch-error) and possible [Google Bug report on Gradle](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210467)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reliably have both `titlebar.xml` and `titlebar.png`. Please rename one to have a different base name.

Comment: Thanks - will change this. However, it was working for me and my customers on a lot of different devices and emulators. What can be the reason for two errors in all those months?

Comment: After renaming the png to a different name and changing its entry in the xml file I NOW receive the error too. Now I'm totally lost. Few customer receive this error if both names are identical and all customer receive this error if the names are different. Arg!

Comment: @hjw: I am assuming that your style is pointing to the XML, and the XML is pointing to the PNGs. Be sure to do a "clean" (Project|Clean in Eclipse, `ant clean install` from command-line), to make sure you are picking up the right resource IDs.

Comment: After one full day it's not working. After several clean and refresh and rebuild I do have a situation where it fails always for parts of my customers.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I solved that adding black parts to the top and left 1 pixel lines. I tried to keep them transparent to avoid the image scale but didn't work.