# Android API 21 9patch error?

Tags: android

In my current development process I've encountered a very strange bug...
On all tested API versions the app runs perfect, smooth and without errors, but only on API 21 I got the following error and I don't have any clue how to fix this.

```
06-08 12:59:49.703 2865-2865/de.eplus.b2p.alditalk.mock_local E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: mypackage, PID: 2865
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.eplus.b2p.alditalk.mock_local/mypackage.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #72: Error inflating class EditText
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2739)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2804)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6066)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #72: Error inflating class EditText
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                at de.eplus.b2p.whitelabel.common.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:290)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6368)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2692)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2804) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6066) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                             Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/abc_edit_text_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020015
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3761)
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3629)
                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:762)
                                                                                at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3991)
                                                                                at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1012)
                                                                                at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:80)
                                                                                at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:76)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:60)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:56)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:112)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1039)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                at de.eplus.b2p.whitelabel.common.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:290) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6368) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2692) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2804) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6066) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                             Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #24: <nine-patch> requires a valid 9-patch source image
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(NinePatchDrawable.java:445)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.inflate(NinePatchDrawable.java:401)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1170)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:185)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1170)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable.inflate(InsetDrawable.java:105)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.cr
```

Can someone help me to fix this? The file

> res/drawable-v21/abc_edit_text_material.xml

is included in the appcompat lib I guess... I have already updated the build tools, cleaned everything multiple times, reinstalled everything and even hardresettet the device, but it didn't changed a thing. I worked a few weeks before... All of a sudden this happened and I don't know what changed... (haven't touched the project)

Comment: `Android API 21 9patch error?` and `res/drawable-v21/abc_edit_text_material.xml` don't match. How is an xml to be ever compared to a 9 patch? And this tells you even more: `Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #24: <nine-patch> requires a valid 9-patch source image`

Comment: Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #24: <nine-patch> requires a valid 9-patch source image

The last cause in the stacktrace

Comment: So, yes, exactly what I added to my previous comment. It's telling you that you are not using a 9 patch **image**. Please note that an **image** is something different from an xml file. I guess you are a bit confused about 9 patches.

Comment: @Rotwang You are wrong in that an XML file can contain a `<nine-patch>` element, which points to a valid 9-patch image in the source path, yet somehow this error can be thrown when trying to inflate that drawable.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Of course. But `9 patch error` presumes an error in the 9 patch **image** structure (i.e.: malormed borders).

Comment: @Rotwang "presumes..." yes; yet I am seeing this error with perfectly valid source images, and perfectly valid source XML drawables, crashing a tiny subset of (mostly Huawei) devices in production. Sometimes there is more the an error than what the message suggests.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier To be verified. Until now, I never encountered this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with the latest gradle plugin version.

I am using:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
```

and I get the same error as you.

You can roll back to this version of plugin to fix the issue:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

However this means you cannot use Instant Run if you are using the Preview Android Studio version.

For reference I am using android studio:

```
Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3
Build #AI-145.2949926, built on June 7, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

I tried on a v21 device and got the error.
On devices running <21 or >21 did not get the error.

Comment: Google appear to be aware of this issue. Hopefully it'll get fixed soon! https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210467

Comment: Bug still manifested on a Huawei device with a build from the stable v2.2.1 release of gradle. Am hoping v2.2.2 fixes the problem. Otherwise there may be a related bug with same stacktrace, but related to Huawei.